# Display Outlook Shared Mailbox in SharePoint

Tags: outlook

Is there any way to show a shared outlook mailbox (meeting room) or multiple mailboxes in SharePoint?

If not what would be the best approach to show users the meeting room mailbox/ mailboxes via their sharepoint workspace?

Currently we show each meeting room in its own page viewer web part. However I would like to evaluate if some other sharepoint functionality might help (for example combining the multiple mailboxes in a single sharepoint calendar).

Comment: I have had this request as well, and the group switched to a Outlook shared mailbox, but would like to have a solution for SharePoint.